# Could we get a more interesting favicon?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, favicon

Some SE sites in beta have *slightly* customized favicons. They are motifs instead of letters, like for example [Poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/) and [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/). I think 'AR' doesn't really relate to the site. Could it be changed to something like this?

Generic Infinity Symbol

[image]

or the Official Arduino [Community Logo](http://arduino.cc/en/Trademark/CommunityLogo#.Uxsnsx-BVWM)

[image]

or the official logo itself (This is trademarked by Arduino)

[image]

Comment: The minus is on the left

Comment: @TheDoctor Thats in the official logo which is trademarked and, as best I understand trademark law, SE cant use it.

Comment: I frequently confuse this proposal with the Arkansas.SE proposal. +∞

Comment: We might want to add the outline of a board for our logo, but that may be too small. A LED?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can! A new "infinity logo" should be showing up on computers near you soon.

Comment: When i first saw the new icon, i thought, Infinity SE??!!?

Comment: Why is it black?  Isn't everything Arduino blue?

Comment: @AwesomeUser This is the meta site, where pretty much everything is grayscale. It's standard for favicons to be black here. On the main site, the logo is in fact blue (although that's actually because blue is the default color for Stack Exchange beta site logos).

Comment: Why didn't I realize that.  I feel stupid now! :p

Comment: @AwesomeUser Don't feel stupid! It's a perfectly reasonable thing to think if you're coming in with an Arduino mindset.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party here. Perhaps I should have created a new meta discussion.

I was part of the first(?) Arduino.SE closed beta which was eventually merged into EE and SO. This was the favicon I created for that purpose. Licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). If that license is incompatible with what we do here at Arduino.SE, I'll gladly make an exception. For the record, I haven't determined if the 16x16 likeness of the Arduino Uno is actually something I can license.

Three different versions each having consecutively fewer components:

[image]
[image]
[image]

A preview of the first:

[image]

Hopefully someone will find these useful.