# New favicon doesn't show up in many places

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon

We got a [new favicon](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/a/145/37) almost two days ago that looks like an infinity symbol. Unfortunately, this isn't showing up in a lot of places, including the dropdown:

> [image]

chat (including the icon on the tab):

> [image]

and pretty much everywhere on http://stackexchange.com, e.g. [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#newest).

This is 100% reproducible on Chrome, Firefox, and IE on two different computers, one of which hasn't even been to Arduino.SE before. I very highly doubt this is a caching problem.

Comment: It's probably just a caching issue. Try using a different browser and see if it's any different.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield That's what I thought at first, but no. Reproduced on Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: I would wait a bit longer if its a server caching issue. If it isn't fixed by then, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson It's not caching; see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, not caching.

Comment: @TheGuy I said *server side*. IIRC there's a lot of caching on the server side.

Comment: @Annon I didn't think server-side caching was possible...

Comment: @TheGuy I meant like that it needs to be updated on multiple servers and they haven't all been updated yet.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Nope, that wouldn't be the cause of this. Servers serving up different content would be fixed in ~15 minutes (can't find the source for this). It's not part of [the sprites file](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=2a2968ded8b1ccc425e160db793c03e1) so that's probably the reason... there may be other places it isn't used, too.

Comment: Most of this is just caching. Try doing a hard refresh on http://cdn.sstatic.net/arduino/img/icon-48.png and you'll see the new icon.

The sprite image does appear to be missing the new icon though: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=ca9619587f38f6088409bc18c44b605b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our sprite maps and favicons were out of date. Fixed in build rev `2014.3.17.1464`.

[image]